# div with click and an anchor tag in it runs both clicks instead of running only the anchor on click

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, getuikit

I have a div with  in it, both have different on click functions. the  also toggles a modal with uikit. When clicking on the  element both on clicks are running and the modal opens. Why? How to prevent the click from running the  onclick?

```
<div onClick=()=>onClickDivFunc>
    <a uk-toggle={`target:#${modalId}`} onClick=()=>onClickAnchorFunc>text</a>
</div>
```

Comment: You can stop the propagation of the inner click event. IMO this is all terrible design as `div`s shouldn't be clickable, or if they need to be they should also specify an aria role of "button" for accessibility reasons. How does a user click on the `div` without also clicking the anchor link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this using `event.stopPropagation`

[Link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation)

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/Lundstromski/pen/YzWyPOO)